# Why does my testnet wallet "disappear"?

Tags: wallet, testnet

I have an instance of Cardano Wallet running and pointing at testnet. I create/restore a wallet like this:

```
curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"name":"My Wallet","mnemonic_sentence":["..."],"passphrase":"..."}' https://myserver.dev/cardano-wallet/v2/wallets
```

and get a successful response back, which includes a valid `walletId`.

For a few minutes, I can successfully query the API using this `walletId`. If I hit the `/wallets/{walletId}/addresses` endpoint, I get back a list of 20 unused addresses, as expected. However, after a short time (I haven't found the exact time but it seems to be around 5 minutes) I start to get a 404 with a response body similar to:

```
{"code":"no_such_wallet","message":"I couldn't find a wallet with the given id: ..."}
```

Is this expected behavior? Is there something else I need to do to ensure the wallet can be found when I need to "create" addresses for it? I know I could always just "restore" it before executing an operation against the wallet, but this seems like it would add a lot of extra potentially unnecessary requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After writing the question, I realized that maybe it was my instance of Cardano Wallet that was the problem. I checked the logs and it looks like the problem is two-fold: 1) I only allocated 1G of memory for the Cardano Wallet Docker container and it was being killed by the OOM killer. 2) I didn't have the wallet db mapped to a persistent volume, so whenever the container was restarted, I would lose my wallet.

So it doesn't appear that this is expected behavior. Host the Cardano Wallet API correctly and you shouldn't have this issue.